# SharePoint 2013 Ribbon Change Functioning of the Scrollbar

Tags: 2013, master-page, ribbon

I have noticed on SharePoint 2013 that the scroll with the ribbon activated differently than when the ribbon is not activated. When the ribbon is activated (clicking the Page Tab), the scroll for s4-workspace starts below the ribbon.

When the Browse button is subsequently hit, the scroll now includes the Header. I would like to have the scroll function just like the ribbon where the header is fixed. Meaning that the scroll would start after the Header.

I am also having my navigation show at all times below the header.

Could someone point me to the CSS to do this?

Answer (score -1):

I simply added below CSS and it worked for me:

```
body{
  overflow-y:auto; 
  overflow-x:auto;   
}
```